# Can a class attribute shadow a built-in in Python?

Tags: python, built-in, flake8

If have some code like this:

```py
class Foo():
   def open(self, bar):
       # Doing some fancy stuff here, i.e. opening "bar"
       pass
```

When I run [`flake8`](https://flake8.pycqa.org/) with the [flake8-builtins](https://pypi.org/project/flake8-builtins/) plug-in I get the error

```
A003 class attribute "open" is shadowing a python builtin
```

I don't understand how the method could possibly shadow the built-in `open`-function, because the method can only be called using an instance (i.e. `self.open("")` or `someFoo.open("")`). Is there some other way code expecting to call the built-in ends up calling the method? Or is this a false positive of the `flake8-builtins` plug-in?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not really a practical case, but your code would fail if you wanted to use the built-it functions on the class level after your shadowed function has been initialized:

```
class Foo:
    def open(self, bar):
        pass

    with open('myfile.txt'):
        print('did I get here?')

>>> TypeError: open() missing 1 required positional argument: 'bar'
```

The same would also be true with other built-in functions, such as `print`

```
class Foo:
    def print(self, bar):
        pass

    print('did I get here?')

>>> TypeError: print() missing 1 required positional argument: 'bar'
```

Comment: That is true, but the functions made in a class are used for class objects. `self.open()` and `open()` are different, so there is no issue.

Comment: I accept this answer because it shows a scenario where the method would indeed shadow the built-in.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't have a problem with the code. As long as the function is referenced with `self.open()` and not `open()`, it should work. Just make sure the class does not already have an `open()` function.

Comment: It's more the other way around that I am worried about: writing `open()` and ending up calling the method instead of the built-in function.

Comment: Yes, but that won't happen because `open()` and `self.open()` are different and cannot be interchangable.